Should the shower valve inside the wall ever get wet?
I suspect a leak inside a shower wall in my new rental because of the crumbling drywall on the very bottom and high moisture meter readings.  The plumbers came in and opened the wall and found no leaks.   After running the shower for 2hrs I found that the shower valve inside the wall where the soft padding is is wet to the touch and there are some super slow drops.  Is this at all normal? Should the plumbers fix it or, is this not possible?   TIA!

Is it also warm to the touch where it gets wet, or could it be due to condensation on the cold supply (there's usually a difference between the sides, but it's possible for the valve body to get condensation on it either directly or from it running down the cold pipe). You may need a shorter test. If it's not condensation, something is leaking, and that's never correct.

Remove the shower head and cap the shower arm. Turn on the shower.  This will pressurize everything throughout the valve and piping to the shower head.  Leave it under pressure for a few minutes if nothing shows up initially.  This will give you a true indication of any leaks.   If nothing shows, then the moisture is coming from condensation.

It's not normal for the shower valve inside the wall to be wet to the touch with slow drops after running the shower. It indicates a potential leak or condensation issue. The plumbers should investigate further and address the problem to prevent any damage.
